# How can I make a list of data frames which have the same values in the first column?

Tags: r

Say I have multiple data frames, and I want to make a multiple lists of the data frames with the same first column. For example, dfs 1-4 have "abc" in all columns of the first row, dfs 5-7 have "def" in all columns of the first row, etc. How can I write a script which puts (in this case) dfs 1-4 in a list called "abc", dfs 5-7 in a list called "def"?

This is my first question, so please let me know if there is anything else I could provide. I researched for a few days with no luck :(

Thanks!

Jack

Comment: Use `rep` ie. `rep(c('abc', 'def'), c(4, 3))`

Comment: So to be sure, what you want is to "sort" different data frames (that you have in a list?) in a list of lists of data frames according to the value in their first row (which is always the same for all columns?)?

Comment: @MisterPositive Hmm, I don't think replicating is what I want to do. I haven't tried much yet, but what I was trying to do is set up an if then statement saying that if the value in [1,1] matches the value of [1,1] in another data frame, then add to a list. However, I am not sure what the syntax for this would be... Any ideas would be really appreciated! Again, sorry for not knowing much R :(

Comment: @F.Privé Yes! That is exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: @JackArnestad Okay, do you want to be guided to the solution, or do you want that I give you the solution?

Comment: @F.Privé Guided to the solution works so that I can learn more :)

Comment: @JackArnestad Give me 5 min.

Comment: @F.Privé Sounds good! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is a guide to the solution, as you asked.

- First make sure you have your list of data frames called `l` (`all(sapply(l, is.data.frame))` should be `TRUE`).
- Then, for each element (`df`) of this list, you need to get the character (string) in the first row (in any column, for example the first one). This will give you a vector of characters and you can get it by using either `sapply` or `purrr::map_chr`.
- After that, here comes the split you want to do. Use `split` for that with as first argument the vectors of indices (see `?seq_along`) and as a second argument the vector of characters you've just computed before.
- Finally, use `lapply` to transform this list of indices in a list of data frames (you need to know the `[` accessor for a list).

If you need more guidance, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: I got the first two steps, but I am a bit lost for the third and fourth ones. So for the third step, if my vector of characters from step two is called "names", would it be split(seq_along(names), names)? And also, how would I do the last step? lapply(names, "[")?

Comment: Yes for the first one and put that in `spl` for example. Tell me if you need help for the last step.

Comment: Yeah, if you could help me with the last step I would appreciate it. I am pretty lost with that, as when I do final <- lapply(spl, "["), I am not getting sorted sub-lists (I think that's what it is supposed to output, or that's what my goal was at least). Thanks!

Comment: Try `lapply(spl, function(ind) l[ind])`.

Comment: Is that OK? If you get what you want, you can validate the answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Guiding to the solution is much more fun than just giving it!